# If repositories are for aggregate roots, where should data access logic for other entities go?

Tags: c#, .net, domain-driven-design

I have a few objects that represent a web application.  Currently I have a cluster object to represent a specific deployment of the app.  Within a cluster object I have the following objects:  Server, Customer, User.  None of these objects can exist without being part of a cluster, so I created a ClusterRepository to retrieve the clusters from the database.  Now, from the cluster I need to get a list of Customers, presumably by using a method in the Cluster object like GetCustomers().  Now, my initial thought was to then offload the work of this operation to a CustomerRepository, but since repositories are only for aggregate roots, where should the data access logic go?  Does this belong in a service class?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Essentially,  an Aggregate root is any object that you might need to fetch as the root of an object graph.  Just because a specific entity is an aggregate root, and has a repository, does not mean that another entity which is one of it's properties can't also be an aggregate root - with it's own repository.

A good example is a customer billing system.  Customer would certainly be an aggregate root,  and would contain a collection of invoices... But for another application function, the invoice itself might be an aggregate root with constituent LineItem objects in it's object graph.

So in your example, there is nothing wrong with creating another repository for customers, if you need to fetch them independantly of clusters in some situations.

NOTE:  See thread in comments as well.  Although root entities can, (and often will) have references to other root entities, it is frowned upon (and that may be too mild a turn of phrase) to allow the repository for any root entity to contain functionality that manages (creates, updates, or deletes) any root entity within its object graph that it has a reference to.  Any such referenced root entities should have their own individual repositories, and the functionality to manage them (Create, Update and/or delete operations) should be in their repository, so that it is only in one place.

Comment: An aggregate root is an object which is responsible for the life cycle of all of it's contained entities.  Aggregate roots exist to maintain valid relationships invariants, fetch access is a consequence of that not the reason for creating an aggregate root. This answer almost seems to suggest an aggregate root arises depending on perspective of the caller.  Invoice is either an aggregate root or it is not.  Period.  To the original question if Customer is treated as an aggregate root, Cluster can still have a reference but Customer is now no longer part of the Cluster aggregate root.

Comment: If I understand your objection correctly, it is equivilent to requiring that there be no overlap within the set of defined aggregates, which which would be unusual and unnecessary. To your other point about basing aggregates on the access requirements of the application domain, I quote from Evans, "...Provide repositories only for AGGREGATE roots that actually need direct access.."  It is of course often the case that entities which are part of one aggregate may need to be directly accessed, with their constituents, in another part of the application.

Comment: Evans p124 "An aggregate is a cluster of associated objects that we treat as a unit for the purpose of data changes."  The root is the object responsible for controlling change/access to all others in the aggregate.  What I object to is an entity which is at times a non root part of one aggregate and at other times the root of it's own aggregate.  The entity could be deleted as a member of first aggregate, after which it could not be in control of it's own aggregate.  A root cannot be part of another aggregate because it is responsible for maintaining it's own aggregate in a valid state.

Comment: I suspect you do not understand the concept.  From Pg 129 of DDD, Evans clearly says "Objects within the AGGREGATE can hold references to other AGGREGATE roots".  The point of separation is at the root.  Aggregate roots CAN be part of other Aggregates, indeed, there is no reasonable way to design a system without allowing this.  What the paradigm frowns on is when the overlap includes non-root objects in more than one aggregate boundary.  That is considered bad because multiple aggregates might inconsistently modify those objects. But the paradigm HAS to allow overlap of root objects.

Comment: You are confusing a reference with aggregate "membership".  Study the car example.  Car is an aggregate root and has entities within it's aggregate.  Engine is also an aggregate root.  Car holds a reference to Engine but Engine is never part of the Car aggregate. By your same argument, if roots overlapped one root could modify another root.  If the mod was a delete, the second root could leave the entities it was responsible for orphaned. An even worse inconsistency.  You will find NO examples in Evans where an object which is an aggregate root is also a member of another aggregate.

Comment: He said the customer can't exist without being part of a cluster..